# Why doesn't an infite loop lock an OS?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, cpu

Say you had a process running some code that looked like this

```
while (true) {
  //do nothing
}
```

Why doesn't this block the OS?

I know that operating systems have a process scheduler (such as CFS on Linux), but how does this actually work?

If code is executing an infinite loop, when does a process scheduler have time to execute its own code?

Wouldn't there need to be something external running that interrupts the running code to yield back to the OS? If so, how does an OS like Linux manage this?

Do CPUs have built-in functionality to manage use-cases like this?

Comment: A hardware interrupt from a peripheral device, (KB, mouse, disk, NIC, USB etc), can cause executuon to switch to a driver, and that may change the set of running threads.  So could a system call from another thread running on another core, (an inter-core driver can interrupt an 'infinite loop').

Comment: Also note that, if the number of ready threads is not greater than the number of cores, the OS scheduler code does not need to be entered.  It has nothing to do until an interrupt/syscall changes something, so it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to understand here is that an operating system is always in control, and it is fully capable of interrupting any process at any time. CPU's also provide hardware support to achieve this.

Most of the contemporary operating systems(including Linux) schedulers can interrupt an executing process. its usually done by using a timer interrupt. its essentially a programmable clock, where you can define what happens on every clock tick.

In Linux the process preemption by scheduler can be defined in following steps

1. CPU local timer interrupt is invoked and the interrupt handler starts executing
2. Now interrupt handler is in control of CPU (***so your infinite loop code is in paused state***)
3. interrupt handler checks if current process should continue to execute (Check priority, time quanta etc)
4. If the process cant be allowed to execute then its preempted and a new process is assigned the CPU

So as you can see any process is never given 100% control of the system and an operating system always have means to stop or kill it.

Comment: 'its usually done by using a timer interrupt'.....what about all the other interrupts from peripherals?  What if there are more cores than ready/running threads?   I am not happy with 'timer interrupt' answers:(

Comment: I am sorry that it make you unhappy, but Linus torvalds is kind of rude person and he always chooses to do things in a way that hurt someone's feeling

Comment: Linus, and linux, are quite happy to have all the I/O completion interrupts cause scheduling runs that can change the set of running threads without any timer interaction.  Windows is the same.

Answer (score 0):

From some research, it looks like computers have a hardware timer called a programmable interval timer (PIT), which the OS can use to set a time in the future to cause an "interrupt" in some milliseconds or nanoseconds in the future.

Comment: "Programmable Interrupt Timer" is standard nomenclature in computer systems that were designed to run Microsoft Windows. Every computer system that is capable of running a _preemptive multitasking_ operating system must have some hardware means to periodically interrupt the running program and invoke the OS scheduler, but not every computer system uses that exact name to describe the hardware. Especially among _microcontrollers_, you will find names like "timer/counter," "heartbeat timer," etc.

Comment: @SolomonSlow that is incorrect.  It is quite possible to run a preemptive scheduler with I/O completions alone, without a timer interrupt.  The timer is convenient for timing out system calls, and for sharing out execution when there are more ready threads than cores, but it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

During each iteration of the loop, a program normally yields its CPU time so that the kernel may have a nice opportunity to schedule some time for other processes to execute. However, this is not strictly necessary, as the CPU is perfectly capable of pausing a program—even one in the middle of an infinite loop—based on receiving any hardware interrupt